# Give fixed order for columns based on column names for different dfs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes that all contain **one or more** of the columns dogs, cats, birds or fish. For all the dataframes I would like to have the order fish, cats, dogs, birds for the columns.

```
df <- data.frame(dogs = c(1:2), cats = c(33:34), birds = c(2:3), fish = c(7:8))
  dogs cats birds fish
1    1   33     2    7
2    2   34     3    8

df2 <- data.frame(dogs = c(5:6), cats = c(103:104), birds = c(4:5))
  dogs cats birds
1    5  103     4
2    6  104     5
```

I would like to get

```
#order fish, cats, dogs, birds
df
  fish cats dogs birds
1    7   33    1     2
2    8   34    2     3

df2
  cats dogs birds
1  103    5     4
2  104    6     5
```

Right now I'm changing the column order for all dataframes manually (`df[,c(4,2,1,3)]` etc) and can't seem to find a way to solve this otherwise. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier option in `base R` is `match` to get the index, specify the `nomatch = 0` so that if there are columns that are not matching, it will not go as `NA`.  Here, we create a function that be used for multiple datasets

```
f1 <- function(dat, names_ord) {
      dat[match(names_ord, names(dat), nomatch = 0)]
 }


nm1 <- c('fish', 'cats', 'dogs', 'birds')
f1(df2, nm1)    
#    cats dogs birds
#1  103    5     4
#2  104    6     5

f1(df, nm1)
#  fish cats dogs birds
#1    7   33    1     2
#2    8   34    2     3
```

---

Or it can be applied at once in a `list` of datasets

```
lapply(list(df, df2), f1, names_ord = nm1)
```

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 select(any_of(c("fish", "cats", "dogs", "birds")))

  fish cats dogs birds
1    7   33    1     2
2    8   34    2     3

df2 %>%
 select(any_of(c("fish", "cats", "dogs", "birds")))

  cats dogs birds
1  103    5     4
2  104    6     5
```

If you have many of such datasets, then with the addition of `purrr`, you can do:

```
map(.x = list(df, df2),
    ~ .x %>%
     select(any_of(c("fish", "cats", "dogs", "birds"))))

[[1]]
  fish cats dogs birds
1    7   33    1     2
2    8   34    2     3

[[2]]
  cats dogs birds
1  103    5     4
2  104    6     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `match` + `na.omit` like below

```
> nmord <- c("fish", "cats", "dogs", "birds")

> df[na.omit(match(nmord, names(df)))]
  fish cats dogs birds
1    7   33    1     2
2    8   34    2     3

> df2[na.omit(match(nmord, names(df2)))]
  cats dogs birds
1  103    5     4
2  104    6     5
```